# Entry point not found in assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design - dotnet.exe crashes

Tags: asp.net-core, crash, entity-framework-core

Please look below for the data given in Package Manager Console. I can't do a Add-Migration. When I do the dotnet.exe crashes.

```
PM> Add-Migration 1
Unhandled Exception: System.MissingMethodException: Entry point not found in assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design, Version=1.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.
PM> dotnet --info
.NET Command Line Tools (1.0.0-preview2-003131)

Product Information:
 Version:            1.0.0-preview2-003131
 Commit SHA-1 hash:  635cf40e58

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.14393
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-x64
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I solved this by removing the Design reference and only using the tools reference.

edit:

Over time gave me another error, from what I can tell the problem is that Microsoft updated their design package but not their tool package, so both don't work together, since if you follow their tutorial it should get the latest package you get an error by following it.

I solved it by forcing both packages to the 1.0.0-preview2-final.
My updated project.json:

```
{
  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": "1.0.1",
    "System.Runtime": "4.1.0",
    "Newtonsoft.Json": "9.0.1",
    "DataAccess": "1.0.0-*",
    "Entities": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },
  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },
  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },
  "runtimes": {
    "win10-x64": {},
    "win8-x64": {},
    "win7-x64": {}
  },
  "scripts": {
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  },
  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  }
}
```

Comment: Microsoft updated both their packages by now and they seem to work well together if you point to the latest version.
The downside is that I can't generate the migration anymore on the Package Manager console, I have to run from the command console: "dotnet ef migrations add migrationame".
The library must be compiled as an executable for it to work as well.

Comment: You have made my day