# Entry point not found in assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design, Version=1.1.0.0

Tags: c#, crash, asp.net-core-mvc

I am getting a similar issue to this post:

[Entry point not found in assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design - dotnet.exe crashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40377865/entry-point-not-found-in-assembly-microsoft-entityframeworkcore-design-dotnet)

I have created an Asp.Net Core MVC Application and project.json looks like this:

```
{

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
      "version": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
      "type": "build"
    },

    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design": {
      "version": "1.1.0",
      "type": "build"
    },

    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "RealEstateCoreApplication.DB": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.1.0",
    "BundlerMinifier.Core": "2.3.327"
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "imports": [
        "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    },

    "Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "imports": [
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "**/*.cshtml",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "bower install", "dotnet bundle" ],
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  },
  "runtimes": {
    "win7-x64": {}
  }
}
```

I have tried a bunch of things but can't set the command: "dotnet ef database update -c IdentityDb" to work in a command window (IdentityDb replaces the default Application Context). Just keeps crashing out saying: Entry point not found in assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design, Version=1.1.0.0

Comment: Did you happen to find a solution for this issue? This exact things is happening when I try to run this.

Answer (score 0):

I ran in the same problem, and after a couple of tests I've found the solution.
Here my project.json

```
"dependencies": {
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies": "1.1.1",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.1.1",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.1.1",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.1.1",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.1.2",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.1.1",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.1.1",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.1.1",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.1.1",
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.1.1",
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design": "1.1.1",
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design": "1.1.1",
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.1.1",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.1.1",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.1.1",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.1.1",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.1.1",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.1.1",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.1.1",
"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.1.0",
"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc": "1.1.0",
"Microsoft.NETCore.App": "1.1.1"},

"buildOptions": {
"emitEntryPoint": true,
"preserveCompilationContext": true},

"frameworks": {
"netcoreapp1.1": {
  "imports": [
    "dotnet5.6",
    "portable-net45+win8"]}},

"tools": {
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
  "version": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
  "imports": [
    "portable-net45+win8"
  ]
},
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet": "1.1.0-preview4-final"}
```

To get it solved you should upgrade to .NET Core 1.1

In the dependencies change Microsoft.NETCore.App to 1.1.1 and in the frameworks section the netcoreapp1.0 reference will need to change to netcoreapp1.1

Important: The name of the tools package has changed from Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools to Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Dotnet

Please, also refer to this http://bencoleman.co.uk/dotnet-core-1-1-gotchas/

I've also upgraded Nuget to version 3.5 [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/)

I hope, it will help you.
Kind regards